# How to get IP and use geocalization api

Tags: javascript, json

```
$.getJSON('https://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/self', function(data) {
 info_location = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
 alert(info_location)
}
```

My code works as you can see, but I want some way to get the provider (isp), how can I get this with javascript?

Comment: Please edit your tags to fit the programming language used!

Comment: @Klaus D. I already edited, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify the data, but if you look at the response from the URL in your browser, ISP information is not there.

If you wanted IP address, then you would do

`alert(data.ipAddress);`